# signed message different on opera and metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am using the following code to sign a message:

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(
  {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: 1,
    method: 'personal_sign',
    params: [
      `My account is ${this.accounts[0]}`,
      this.accounts[0],
    ],
  },
  (err, res) => {
     // send res.result to server
  },
);
```

on the server i do the following:

```
// Recover the public key
const candidate = web3.eth.accounts.recover(`My account is ${account}`, signature);

// Verify the recovered key and the key making the request are the same
return ethUtil.toChecksumAddress(candidate) === ethUtil.toChecksumAddress(myPublicKey)
```

This works correctly when using MetaMask, but the recovered address does not match when using Opera on android. From what I can tell both are using v0.20.7 of web3. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: does it work if you use web3.personal.sign?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error that personal sign is not supported @haxerl

Comment: does it work when you change personal_sign to eth_sign or maybe try use send instead of sendAsync? and btw i though they have deprecated sendAsync function which resources did you read?

Comment: can you provide signed messages for both ? or transactions we can take the message from ?

Answer (score 1):

When using MetaMask you have a different public/private key.

Therefore another value gets returned.

Comment: I don't expect the values to be the same. I expect that `web3.eth.accounts.recover` gives me the correct address when recovering the signed message. However, when signing a message with Opera the address does not match that of the signing address when using the `web3.eth.accounts.recover` method